# Introducing a controllable space in a table

Tags: tables, spacing

How can I introduce some vertical spaces in the table before the headers in Latex. The method I use below has introduced a gap, but the gap is too big. How can I have a more controllable vertical gap?

```
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular*}{0.95\columnwidth}{l|l}
        \hline
         Parameters & ~ \\ \hline
         \rule{0pt}{3pt} & ~ \\

        ~ & ~ \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular*}
    \caption{}
\label{Tbl:X}
\end{table}
```

Comment: See the answer to [Column padding in tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31704/5764) for different ways of padding rows/columns with whitespace.

Answer (score 5):

LaTeX doesn't really have a perfect answer for it. You can add or substract space vertically by using `\\[<value>]`. However this will appear above the rule if you use `\hline`.

So a poor man's solution would be:

```
\begin{tabular*}{0.95\columnwidth}{l|l}
    \hline
     Parameters & ~ \\ \hline
       &            \\[-5pt]        % adjust value as necessary                            
     x & y \\ \hline
```

Comment: anyway to get this below the line?

Comment: @Androidian my solution shows a way to get a space below the line by producing an empty table row and backtrack.  That is the only "out-of-the-box" solution available. The `array` package also has `\extrarowheight`, but that applies to all rows not to individual ones.